# Add text to an object(the white circle) in three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, three.js, texture-mapping

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u8n2zgn/) which shows what I have at the moment. I would like to add a text 3D/2D doesn't matter. The text should rotate along with the rotation of the white circle. Any method is preferred as long as the intended result is obtained. Here is the code.

**three.js code**

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,

    mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0,

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2,

    SEPARATION = 200,
    AMOUNTX = 100,
    AMOUNTY = 10,

    camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    var container, separation = 100,
        amountX = 50,
        amountY = 50,
        particles, particle;

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.y = 5800;
    camera.position.z = 1000;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // particles

    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial({

        color: 0xffffff,
        program: function (context) {

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(0, 0, 9.5, 0, PI2, true);
            context.fill();

        }

    });
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        particle = new THREE.Sprite(material);
        particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;

        particle.position.normalize();
        particle.position.multiplyScalar(Math.random() * 10 + 450);
        particle.scale.multiplyScalar(10);
        scene.add(particle);

    }

    // lines

    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

        var vertex = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1);
        vertex.normalize();
        vertex.multiplyScalar(1850);

        geometry.vertices.push(vertex);

        var vertex2 = vertex.clone();
        vertex2.multiplyScalar(Math.random() * 0.3 + 1);

        geometry.vertices.push(vertex2);

        var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            opacity: Math.random()
        }));
        scene.add(line);
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

    //

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

//

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
}

function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {

    if (event.touches.length > 1) {

        event.preventDefault();

        mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;

    }

}

function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {

    if (event.touches.length == 1) {

        event.preventDefault();

        mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;

    }

}

//

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    render();

}

function render() {

    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
    camera.position.y += (-mouseY + 200 - camera.position.y) * .05;

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I would like to add a text 3D/2D doesn't matter." - This doesn't make sense

Comment: :P I am new to this, ignore if that sounded funny, I just wanna add some text there "Hello World", to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple 3D text, i found it in an old file i had:
you need the source too:

```
 <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.js"></script>

 var MyWords = "Thomas Sebastian";
 var shape = new THREE.TextGeometry(MyWords, {font: 'helvetiker',size:'24',curveSegments: 20, weight: 'normal',height : 4,hover:30});
 var wrapper = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x65676,ambient: 0x030303, specular: 0x009900, shininess: 30});
 var words = new THREE.Mesh(shape, wrapper);
 words.position.x=-80;
 words.position.z=0;
 words.position.y=20;
 scene.add(words);
```

The Result :)

[image]

Comment: Wow!! This works. But there is a serious performance hit.. Is that expected?

Comment: You can always put the segments down

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1u8n2zgn/5/ all your sprites move to a vertex shader....  too much going on for the cpu....